# How can I see all the search results in the Gmail app when I query `is:unread is:inbox`?

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail

I've noticed that when I query `is:unread is:inbox` in the Gmail app, I only see results back to ~June 1:

[image]

However, I do have many more (>2k) emails that are older than June 1 and  match `is:unread is:inbox`.

How can I see all the search results in the Gmail app when I query `is:unread is:inbox`?

I've tried on Wifi and on 4G. I tried several different days. Gmail won't show older emails and I wonder if there is a workaround or a setting for that.